# How to calculate that conditional expectation?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I mean the expectation of `x*z` under the conditions `(y + z == 8) && (z*w == 2) && (w + y == 1)`, where `x,y,z,w` are IID having  `ExponentialDistribition[1]`. The command

```
Expectation[x*z \[Conditioned] (y + z == 8) && (z*w == 2) && (w + y == 
1), {x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], 
z \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], w \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}]
```

returns the input as well as `NExpectation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one reduces the conditions (with the implicit condition that $Z>0$ given that $Z$ has an exponential distribution with mean 1), one finds

```
Reduce[(y + z == 8) && (z*w == 2) && (w + y == 1) && z > 0] // LogicalExpand
(* w == 4/(7 + Sqrt[57]) && y == 8 + 1/2 (-7 - Sqrt[57]) && z == 1/2 (7 + Sqrt[57]) *)
```

So the distribution of $X Z$ conditioned on $Z=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{57}+7\right)$ is just a multiple of the distribution of $X$ given that $X$ is independent of all of the other random variables.  The expectation of $\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{57}+7\right) X$ is $\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{57}+7\right) E(X)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{57}+7\right) * 1=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{57}+7\right)$.

Or using *Mathematica*:

```
d = ExponentialDistribution[1];
Expectation[x*z \[Conditioned] Reduce[(y + z == 8) && (z*w == 2) && (w + y == 1) && z > 0] //LogicalExpand, 
  {w \[Distributed] d, x \[Distributed] d, y \[Distributed] d, z \[Distributed] d}]
(* 1/2 (7 + Sqrt[57]) *)
```

It didn't work the way you did it because without including the condition $Z>0$ one obtains:

```
Reduce[(y + z == 8) && (z*w == 2) && (w + y == 1)] // LogicalExpand
(* (8 - z == y && -7 + z == w && z == 1/2 (7 - Sqrt[57])) || 
(8 - z == y && -7 + z == w && z == 1/2 (7 + Sqrt[57]))
```

That more complicated expression I guess is more than *Mathematica* can handle.

Comment: `Expectation[
 x z \[Conditioned] (y == -2 && z == -4 && 
    w == -(1/2)), {x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], 
  y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], 
  z \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], 
  w \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}]` returns `-4`. This is a bug.

Comment: Is it a bug when you condition on 3 things that are impossible to occur if the distributions are exponential?

Comment: The result of the execution `-4` is wrong. The command should return the input.  I submitted a report.

Answer (score 3):

```
cons = (y + z == 8) && (z*w == 2) && (w + y == 1);
```

There are three equations with three variables. The variables are all constants.

```
values = SolveValues[{cons, z > 0}, {w, y, z}]

(* {{4/(7 + Sqrt[57]), 8 + 1/2 (-7 - Sqrt[57]), 1/2 (7 + Sqrt[57])}} *)

Expectation[x*z \[Conditioned] z == values[[1, 3]], 
 x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]]
```

[image]

Which is consistent with

```
values[[1, 3]]*Mean[ExponentialDistribution[1]] // Simplify

(* 1/2 (7 + Sqrt[57]) *)
```

Comment: Good answer.  You beat me by a minute.

Comment: Both answers use the same idea. I prefer @JimB's one as more automated and accurate. How may a conditional expectation be `Piecewise`?

Comment: The `Piecewise` is an unsimplified result. The "condition" can be assumed to be true so the default value cannot occur and simplification with that assumption would remove the `Piecewise`. The last statement is equivalent to `Assuming[z == values[[1, 3]], Expectation[x*z, x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]]]`